# Inefficiently using strstr and strchr

Tags: c

While reviewing my code, my professor said that my use of `strstr` and `strchr` results in a lot of wasted resources as every and each one of them scans the string.

Can I reduce the amount of functions in a good way?

This code scans a string and based on set parameters decides whether the input is valid or not.
`ch1` is `'@'` and `ch2` is `'.'`,  (`email[i]`) is the string.

```
    for (i = 0; email[i] != 0; i++) {
        {
            if (strstr(email, "@.") ||
                strstr(email, ".@") ||
                strstr(email, "..") ||
                strstr(email, "@@") ||
                email[i] == ch1 ||
                email[i] == ch2 ||
                email[strlen(email) - 1] == ch1 ||
                email[strlen(email) - 1] == ch2) {
                printf("The entered e-mail '%s' does not pass the required parameters, Thus it is invalid\n", email);
            } else {
                printf("The email '%s' is a valid e-mail address\n",email);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is the snippet I'm talking about.

Should I write my own code that does the checking once? if so, can you give me some pointers in that regards?
thank you.

EDIT: Thank you very much for your responses, I did learn of the mistakes in my code and hopefully I learn from them.
Thanks again!

EDIT:2: I want to thank you again for your responses, they have helped me immensely, and I believe that I have written better code

```
int at_count = 0, dot_count = 0, error1 = 0, error2 = 0;
int i;
size_t length = strlen(email);
int ch1 = '@', ch2 = '.';

for ( i = 0; email[i] != '\0'; i++)  /* for loop to count the occurance of the character '@' */
    {
    if ( email[i] == ch1)
        at_count++;
    }

for ( i = 0; email[i] != '\0'; i++)  /* for loop to count the occurance of the character '.' */
    {
    if ( email[i] == ch2)
        dot_count++;
    }

if ( email[0] == ch1 || email[0] == ch2 || email[length-1] == ch1 || email[length-1] == ch2 )
        {
    error1++;
        }
else
        {
    error1 = 0;
        }


if ( strstr(email,".@") || strstr(email, "@.") || strstr(email, "..") || strstr(email, "@@"))
        {
    error2++;
        }
else
        {
    error2 = 0;
        }

if ( (at_count != 1) || (dot_count < 1) || (error1 == 1) || (error2 == 1))
    {
    printf("The user entered email address '%s' is invalid\n", email);
    }
else
    {
    printf("'%s' is a valid email address\n", email);
    }
```

I feel this is more elegant and simpler code, also more efficient.
My main inspiration was @chqrlie, as I felt his code was very nice and easy to read.
Is there anyway I can improve?
(The email checks are only for practice, don't mind them!)
 Thank you very much everyone!

Comment: First of all I'm not sure why do you need `for` loop as it breaks at `1st` iteration itself.

Comment: Did your professor actually profile the code and find that the "wasted resources" are both measurable and significant?  Because it seems your professor has lost track of the reason we use computers in the first place:  to do things so we don't have to.  The code works and it looks like it's easy to understand.  Until someone **demonstrates** a performance problem with a bit of code, there is **NO** performance problem or any "wasted resources".

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think he meant in performance, a.k.a that I use strstr too much, or something like that.

Comment: @Math_Seeker So what?  That's the answer your professor deserves. **SO WHAT?** The hardest thing about writing code is to make it work.  To make it work, it has to be understandable and maintainable. Quite often the most efficient response to code running too slow or using too much memory is to buy a faster computer or just add RAM.  Hardware is cheap and reliable.  Human labor is expensive and creates bugs.

Comment: @Math_Seeker Not only that, if you're validating user input of an email address (which is what it looks like you're doing...), the computer will run all those `strstr()` calls in what?  300 microseconds instead of the 200 microseconds it would take to run the more complex, unmaintainable, bug-prone code your professor seems to be pushing?  Do you think the user will notice that difference?  Your professor needs to spend time responsible for making code work, and getting called in at 3 AM when it doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for taking the time to respond, I will try and reason with my professor.

Comment: @Math_Seeker  Good.  Because you don't do performance and resource analysis by looking at code.  No, you don't.  When one of the ways you make a living making high-end large scale systems run faster, you learn that looking at code and trying to predict performance problems is wasted time.  You **run** the code and **profile** it - **measuring** the bottlenecks. Then you fix **those**.  FWIW, the repeated use of `strstr()` on the same string is probably pretty efficient, actually, as that string will be in the hottest cache - if an optimzing compiler does't totally rewrite it anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the professor is right, there is a better way to do the check. The code is a mess, under certain conditions it will print the same error a lot of times. While I agree on parts of your comments, I disagree on the general outcome. You are replying to a student, let him learn the best practices.

Comment: Your professor has a valid beef.  You are learning to code in C, if you go "meh, computers are fast enough anyway" then you might as well learn Java.  It is pretty easy to do, at a minimum use strlen() only once, store its return value in a variable.  You can easily eliminate several strstr() calls as well with a single strchr() to find '@'.  It is only the exercise that matters, the program will never be used.

Comment: @HansPassant the problem is that the substrings "@." and ".@" and ".." cannot be in the input string, they are parameters. So I am using strstr three times, once for each substring, finding "@" is simple enough, its done in another part of my code. So is there a way I can reduce the amount of strstr functions or not? like a user implemented function?any advice if possible?. Thanks for your time!

Comment: The way you've written the `strstr()` calls means that the answer they give does not change on each iteration of the loop. As it stands, those four tests could be done before the loop. Even if you use `strstr(&email[i], "@.")`, you would still not really get any difference in the results if the verboten strings (`".@"`, `"@."`, `".."`) were absent — you would eventually spot the difference if they were present.  It isn't clear what `ch1`, `ch2` are set to. The test for those characters at the end of the string won't change on each iteration, either. 6 of 8 tests don't change — that's wasteful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so if I am understanding correctly, its better to put those tests that don't change before the loop, as opposed to putting them inside the loop, which would be wasteful. did I get that right?

Comment: That's my thesis; it might even be your professor's thesis.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much for the response, I will contact my professor and ask him about that in more detail.

Comment: Hmmm; there's also room to think that you can't know whether the email address is valid until the loop completes.  You can spot invalid addresses when you spot the invalid character(s); you can only tell that the address as a whole is valid when you've checked it all.  When you spot a problem, you could print and break the loop.  You might decide to just set a variable (`bool isValid = true;` before the loop; `isValid = false; break;` when you spot a problem in the loop; `if (isValid) printf("OK\n"); else printf("Invalid\n");` after the loop.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Maybe you work in a domain where the things you say are true. But those are not applicable here for two reasons. One, this is a teaching situation, where simplified programs are used as training for future problems. The fact that `strstr` takes only a few dozen microseconds is irrelevant to learning optimization techniques that apply when working with code that takes seconds, hours, or days. It is the technique, the knowledge, that is valuable here, not the computing time of student programs. Two, other people work in other domains, where the things you say do not hold.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: For example, there are people who work on software that is executed humongous numbers of times, and saving 200 microseconds per execution more than pays for the time it takes them to optimize. Also, it is not true that trying to predict performance problems is wasted time. Again, that may be true in a domain in which you work, but it is not true generally. It is certainly valuable for programmers to understand the effects of the code they write and to design with an eye to optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code indeed has multiple problems:

```
for (i = 0; email[i] != 0; i++) {   // you iterate for each character in the string.
    {   //this is a redundant block, remove the extra curly braces
        if (strstr(email, "@.") ||  // this test only needs to be performed once
            strstr(email, ".@") ||  // so does this one
            strstr(email, "..") ||  // so does this one
            strstr(email, "@@") ||  // again...
            email[i] == ch1 ||      // this test is only performed once
            email[i] == ch2 ||      // so is this one
            email[strlen(email) - 1] == ch1 ||  // this test is global
            email[strlen(email) - 1] == ch2) {  // so is this one
            printf("The entered e-mail '%s' does not pass the required parameters, Thus it is invalid\n", email);
        } else {
            printf("The email '%s' is a valid e-mail address\n", email);
        }
        break;  // you always break from the loop, why have a loop at all?
    }
}
```

You do scan the string 4 times to test the various patterns and another 2 times for `strlen()`. It should be possible to perform the same tests in the course of a single scan.

Note also that more problems go unnoticed:

- there should be a single `@` present
- there should not be any spaces
- more generally, the characters allowed in the address are limited.

Some of the tests seem overkill: why refuse `..` before the `@`, why refuse a trailing `.` before the `@`?

Here is a more efficient version:

```
int at_count = 0;
int has_error = 0;
size_t i, len = strlen(email);

if (len == 0 || email[0] == ch1 || email[0] == ch2 ||
    email[len - 1] == ch1 || email[len - 1] == ch2) {
    has_error = 1;
}

for (i = 0; !has_error && i < len; i++) {
    if (email[i] == '.') {
        if (email[i + 1] == '.' || email[i + 1] == '@') {
            has_error = 1;
        }
    } else if (email[i] == '@') {
        at_count++;
        if (i == 0 || i == len - 1 || email[i + 1] == '.' || email[i + 1] == '@') {
            has_error = 1;
        }
    }
    // should also test for allowed characters         
}

if (has_error || at_count != 1) {
    printf("The entered e-mail '%s' does not pass the required tests, Thus it is invalid\n", email);
} else {
    printf("The email '%s' is a valid e-mail address\n", email);
}
```

Comment: These comments helped me realize the need to understand when a test needs to be performed once or multiple times, also these tests like; ".." are mandatory for the assignment, and some of them don't make much sense like you said. I will try to understand your proposed method, and try to work out a solution on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what a global test is? the one you mentioned in the comments?.

Comment: @Math_Seeker: a test that does not depend on `i`, hence does not need to be repeated for each character in `email`.

Answer (score 3):

Your professor has a good point about the inefficiency in repetitively scanning characters in `email`. Optimally, each character should be scanned only once. Whether you use a `for` loop and string indexing (e.g. `email[i]`) or simply walk-a-pointer down the `email` string is up to you, but you should be locating each character only once. Instead, in your current code you are doing

`for` ***every character*** in `email`, you

- scan `email` 4-times with `strstr` to locate a given substring, and
- scan to the end of `email` 2-times with `strlen`

Think about it. For *every character* in `email`, you are calling `strlen` twice which scans forward over the entire contents of `email` looking for the *nul-terminating* character. All four of your `strstr` calls are locating two character in differing combinations. You could at minimum scan for one or the other and then check the prior character and the one that follows.

[@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) points out additional character combinations and conditions that should be checked for, but since I presume this is a learning exercise rather than something intended for production code, it is enough to be aware that additional criteria are needed to make an e-mail validation routine.

While there is nothing wrong with including `string.h` and for longer strings (generally larger than 32-chars), the optimizations in the `string.h` function will provide varying degrees of improved efficiency, but there is no need to incur any function call overhead. Regardless what you are looking for in your input, you can always walk down your string with a pointer checking each character and taking the appropriate actions as needed.

A short additional example of that approach to your problem, using the lowly `goto` in lieu of a error flag, could look something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "",    /* buffer to hold email */
        *p = buf;           /* pointer to buf  */
    short at = 0;           /* counter for '@' */

    fputs ("enter e-mail address: ", stdout);
    if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {     /* read/validate e-mail */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    while (*p && *p != '\n') {  /* check each character in e-mail */
        if (*p == '@')          /* count '@' - exactly 1 or fail */
            at++;
        if (p == buf && (*p == '@' || *p == '.'))   /* 1st char '@ or .' */
            goto emailerr;
        /* '@' followed or preceded by '.' */
        if (*p == '@' && (*(p+1) == '.' || (p > buf && *(p-1) == '.')))
            goto emailerr;
        /* sequential '.' */
        if (*p == '.' && (*(p+1) == '.' || (p > buf && *(p-1) == '.')))
            goto emailerr;
        p++;
    }   /* last char '@' or '.' */
    if (*(p-1) == '@' || *(p-1) == '.' || at != 1)
        goto emailerr;

    if (*p == '\n')     /* trim trailing '\n' (valid case) */
        *p = 0;

    printf ("The email '%s' is a valid e-mail address\n", buf);
    return 0;

  emailerr:;
    while (*p && *p != '\n')    /* locate/trim '\n' (invalid case) */
        p++;
    if (*p == '\n')
        *p = 0;
    printf ("The email '%s' is an invalid e-mail address\n", buf);
    return 1;
}
```

As mentioned there are many ways to go about the e-mail validation, and to a large degree you should not focus on "micro optimizations", but instead focus on writing logical code with sound validation. However, as your professor as pointed out, at that same time your logic should not be needlessly repetitive injecting inefficiencies into the code. Writing efficient code takes continual practice. A good way to get that practice is to write sever different versions of your code and then either dump your code to assembly and compare or time/profile your code in operation to get a sense of where inefficiencies may be. Have fun with it.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I think I got the gist of your comment, but one question : How does one go about dumping their code code to assembly?

Comment: You do that with the compiler, e.g. for gcc to dump with intel syntax, you would use `gcc -S -masm=intel -o yourcode.asm yourcode.c` (you can add your optimization, e.g. `-O[0-3]` or `-Ofast` to see the way the compiler is optimizing your code based on the optimization level).

Answer (score 0):

Consider `strpbrk`. Possibly all conditions can be evaluated with one pass through the email.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void) {
    char email[1000] = "";
    char at = '@';
    char dot = '.';
    char *find = NULL;
    char *atfind = NULL;
    char *dotfind = NULL;
    int atfound = 0;

    if ( fgets ( email, sizeof email, stdin)) {
        email[strcspn ( email, "\n")] = 0;//remove trailing newline
        find = email;
        while ( ( find = strpbrk ( find, "@."))) {//find a . or @
            if ( find == email) {
                printf ( "first character cannot be %c\n", *find);
                return 0;
            }
            if ( 0 == *( find + 1)) {
                printf ( "email must not end after %c\n", *find);
                return 0;
            }
            //captures .. @@ .@ @.
            if ( dot == *( find + 1)) {
                printf ( ". cannot follow %c\n", *find);
                return 0;
            }
            if ( at == *( find + 1)) {
                printf ( "@ cannot follow %c\n", *find);
                return 0;
            }
            if ( dot == *( find)) {
                dotfind = find;
            }
            if ( at == *( find)) {
                atfind = find;
                atfound++;
                if ( atfound > 1) {
                    printf ( "multiple @\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            find++;
        }
        if ( !atfind) {
            printf ( "no @\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if ( !dotfind) {
            printf ( "no .\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if ( atfind > dotfind) {
            printf ( "subsequent to @, there must be a .\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf ( "problem fgets\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf ( "good email\n");
    return 0;
}
```